# Overleaf - eps files

Tags: latex

I have an issue with eps on the Overleaf platform. A minimal example is in the link below:

https://www.overleaf.com/8173131955vsxptnjhgqsh

The platform does not generate the file and, hence, cannot add it to the file. Since I know latex just from an user's perspective, I am not in the position to describe what is happening whatsoever. If someone have the same issue, I am glad to know the given solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a relative path to refer to a file in overleaf, the path is relative to the location of the current TeX file (**main.tex's working directory is the root directory**). So, if the location of your "main.tex" file changes, you may need to update your relative paths to make sure they still point to the correct location.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ex6states.eps}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}
```

which requires the file `ex6states.eps`. However, your project includes the following files:

[image]

`ex6astates.eps` is not the same as `ex6states.eps`! So, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{ex6astates.eps}
  \caption{The Universe}
  \label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that was a noob one. :facepalm:. In a more complex scenario, would it be possible that the required graphicx package conflicts with any other library? Even with correct typing, in this more complex scenario "https://www.overleaf.com/read/bkjvjxsbsrxm", the graphic does not show. (See listas/Lista2/exercises/ex5.tex)

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto: Your images are all specified with a complete path within the project. However, they need to be relative to the main `.tex` file inside `listas/Lista2/report`. So your images should be `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/ex5control.eps}`, say.

Comment: Thanks once more. I missed the platform and awaited some behaviour sthat was not planned to.